# Android: Retaining data, multiple language support and retaining last applied settings when the app reloads

Tags: android

I have developed an an android app which takes some text as input but the as soon as the orientation changes the the TextView becomes empty.
Also I want to add multiple language support to my app through the settigs button(settings.xml).

Is there a way to fix the TextView issue and then retain the last language used in the next app launch?

E.g. If I set French as my new language from the settings. The next time I open my app the language should be French not English(the default language).

Can anybody help me to fix this?

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `SharedPreference` once setting is set for one language you just store which is selected in `sharedPreference` then you can use next time. Everytime app restarts you can check which language is set.

For your orientation change issue you may use different layout for landscape as well as portrait. To avoid this you can use `onSaveInstanceState` and `onRestoreInstanceState`

Comment: Thank you..  I will make necessary modification and let you know if that works..  Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

For rotation, you have to save and restore the activity's state. You can find more information on how to do that in the [official docs here](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html).

For saving the set language, and any other small data that you want to persist between app sessions, you should use the `SharedPreferences` framework. You can find more information on that also in the official docs [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref).

Comment: Thank you..  I will make necessary modification and let you know if that works..  Thank you :)

Comment: These are the officially recommended ways to do what you need. They will work.